# Set Java version in desktop

Tags: java, java-7

I am using Windows pc and trying to set the Java version to jdk1.7. I had jre1.8 preinstalled in my pc and have now installed jdk1.7.0_80. Both are there in Program Files. But even if I add JAVA_HOME to jdk1.7 and add it to path, the Java -version is showing jdk1.8. I want to change it to point jdk1.7.0_80.

Can anyone please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Have you removed the 1.8 jre from JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: I assume you mean: you open a command line shell, and there you get the wrong java?

Comment: The jre1.8 is not set in Java Home but is there in Program Files

Comment: Yes, I open command line shell and get wrong java. Is there any rule that if I have multiple versions of Java in Program files, only the most recent version will be picked?